# Workarounds for unevaluated results of ContourIntegrate of non-analytic functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

There is a new useful command [`ContourIntegrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourIntegrate.html) since 13.3.
I find that the command is well-done, but even the Sun has spots.
`ContourIntegrate` also deals with non-analytic functions (see *Scope/Special Topic:
Non-analytic Functions* in the documentatation).

However, the command fails for

```
ContourIntegrate[-2*Abs[z] + 3*Conjugate[z] + Arg[z], z ∈ Circle[{0, 0}, 2, {0, Pi}]]
```

silently returning the input, as well as for

```
ContourIntegrate[-2*Abs[z] + 3*Conjugate[z] + Arg[z], z ∈ {"UpperSemicircle", 2, -2}]
```

If the integrand is shortened,

```
ContourIntegrate[-2*Abs[z] + 3*Conjugate[z], z ∈ {"UpperSemicircle", 2, -2}]
```

then the warning

> "ResidueSum::cmero: -2 Abs[z]+3 Conjugate[z]
> is not a meromorphic function of z on the solution set of Im[z]>0."

is produced.

There is a simple manual workaround with `Integrate`:

```
Integrate[ComplexExpand[(-2*Abs[2*Exp[I*t]] + 3*Conjugate[2*Exp[I*t]] + 
 Arg[2*Exp[I*t]])*2*I*Exp[I*t]], {t, 0, Pi}] // ComplexExpand
```

> `6 - 2 π + I (-4 + 12 π)`

Are there any such workarounds for the following two cases which both return unevaluated inputs?

```
f = 3*Conjugate[z] - 2*Abs[z] + Arg[z];
reg1 = Rectangle[{-5/2, -5/2}, {-1, -1}];
reg2 = Annulus[{0, 0}, {1/2, 1}, {Pi/4, 2*Pi/3}];

ContourIntegrate[f, z ∈ reg1]
ContourIntegrate[f, z ∈ reg2]
```

Comment: Where is the question? If you believe there is a bug, report it to Wolfram Support.

Comment: @Domen: "Are there such workarounds for...?"